# partial dependence plot for categorical variable

Tags: r, plot

I have currently constructed a partial dependence plot for a categorical variable (with many levels) see below for snippet, however I only want to show the plot with one of the levels specifically. How can I go about doing this? 
[image]

````
par.AOO91 <- partial(fm.trt, pred.var = c("Area_of_Origin"), chull = TRUE)
plot.AOO91 <- autoplot(par.AOO91, contour = TRUE)
plot.AOO91```
````

Comment: `ggplot` (called via `autoplot` in this case) will plot the data you give it. If you only want to plot some of your data, use standard subsetting operations to only give it the data you want plotted. You don't show any sample data, but something like `autoplot(subset(par.A0091, categorical_variable_name %in% c("One level you want", "A second level you want")), contour = TRUE)`

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you kindly!